# node js POST mysite/uploads 404 (Not Found) when uploaded to azure but works locally

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, azure, http-status-code-404

I'm working on an upload project for a small webpage and I made it all work locally, I can upload files, I can manipulate them and I can get necessary data in response. I pushed the whole thing on azure last night and now when I try to upload something I get

```
POST mysite/uploads 404 (Not Found)
```

My file.html

```
<form id="uploadForm" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/uploads" method="post">
<input type="file" name="userPhoto" class="btn btn-wire" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

html-file.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

$('#uploadForm').submit(function () {
        $("#status").empty().text("File is uploading...");
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            error: function (xhr) {
                $("#status").text('Error: ' + xhr.status);
                //alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
            },
            success: function (response) {
               // var test = JSON.stringify(response[1], null, 4);
               // console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
                files = [];
                $(response).each(function (index) {
                    files.push(response[index]);
                })
                refreshFiles();
                alert("alertsuccess");
                $("#status").empty().text("File is uploaded...");                  
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

nodeapp.js

```
app.use(multer({

dest: "./uploads",
onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
    console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');  
},
onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
    values = JSON.stringify(file);
    console.log(values);
    test.push({ "url": file.path, "filename": file.name, "fileType": file.extension });


}
}));
 app.post('/uploads'), function (req, res) {
        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.end("Error uploading the file!");
            }
            else {


                //res.json({ "test": "test123" });
                res.json(test)
                // res.write(JSON.stringify(test, null, 4));

                res.end();
                test = [];
            }
        })
    })
```

There's quite a bit more code but for the sake of simplicity and my general suspiciousness on this particular part of project I posted only these snippets.

Comment: Have you restarted the application after pushing your new route?

Comment: I didn't find it necessary since it was pushed for the first time, but after your comment I went and restarted the application, nothing changed. The problem is still here.

Comment: Typo app.post('/upload'**)** <- shouldn't be there

Comment: Even if I take the app.post outside of app.use I still get the same error.

Comment: Also the app.post should be outside the app.use(multer because otherwise the post route /uploads doesn't exist until onFileUploadComplete is called and also app.post('/uploads... would be called repeatedly every time file upload completes which is wrong.

Comment: Its moved right now, it was inside because I was trying some file manipulation and file is not defined outside of app.use(multer). But as I said even when it's outside I still get the same error. I updated the code.

Comment: @Molda since you seem like an experienced person, I'd like to point out that when I work locally the app never goes to localhost:port/uploads because of the `return false;` in ajaxSubmit function and if I try to open localhost:port/uploads I'd get 404 just like on the server.

Comment: I meant the bracket **)** that's the typo I was talking about

Comment: You are missing `}));` to close app.use just before app.post and it is at the last line. So basicly app.post is still inside app.use. I'm on my phone so can't help you more right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you deployment to Azure Web Apps? As Node.js applications running on Azure Web Apps are hosted on IIS via IISNode. So there is a `web.config` file required  to config your application on IIS.

You may check this file in your root directory of your site, whether it is in the correct configurations.

Here is a sample of a `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
          <handlers>
               <!-- indicates that the app.js file is a node.js application to be handled by the iisnode module -->
               <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
          </handlers>
          <rewrite>
               <rules>

                    <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                        <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                    </rule>

                    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                    <rule name="StaticContent">
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                    </rule>

                    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
                    <rule name="DynamicContent">
                         <conditions>
                              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                         </conditions>
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
                    </rule>

               </rules>
          </rewrite>
          <!-- You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options -->
        <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="*.js;node_modules\*;routes\*.js;views\*.jade"/>-->
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I deployed it trough git and got the web.config in the right place, with correct configuration, BUT my POST and GET were disabled so after enabling them in web.config I got it working. So your answer is basically the correct one.